# MBSTRING extension not working in RED HAT ENTERPRISE LINUX

Tags: php, linux, redhat, mbstring

Im running my server on Red Hat Enterprise Linux with Weblogic server, I have PHP5.3 installed  on this, recently for one of my project I had to use MBSTRING extension, Ive noticed that was not installed before and I did it.
But still the PHP is unable to recognize this extension,
is there any confrontational setup to do after installing?

please help me.

Comment: How did you install it? Did you load the extension in php.ini?

Comment: @Svenskunganka I installed it using yum install php-mbstring, do I need to configure anything in php.ini?

Comment: have you restarted the web server? (normally I would expect yum doing it, but however, I would try it)

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, I have restarted it, many times, but no luck

Comment: once would have been enough :) .. Is it a managed server or a root server?

Comment: what gives you `php -i | grep -i mbstring` ?

Comment: its a lengthy response, unable to paste here

Comment: License version 2.1.
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

Comment: Just a hint: you can either add such output to the question (preferred in this case) or if it gets to large, then you can use a pastebin and post the link here...

Comment: back to the problem, it looks like the mbstring extension is indeed installed, what makes you think that it isn't? Can you show some example code which is not working?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Core [1] => date [2] => ereg [3] => libxml [4] => pcre [5] => sqlite3 [6] => ctype [7] => dom [8] => fileinfo [9] => filter [10] => hash [11] => iconv [12] => json [13] => oci8 [14] => SPL [15] => PDO [16] => pdo_sqlite [17] => session [18] => posix [19] => Reflection [20] => standard [21] => SimpleXML [22] => SQLite [23] => Phar [24] => tokenizer [25] => xml [26] => xmlreader [27] => xmlwriter [28] => apache2handler ) MBSTRING NOT RUNNING

Comment: Ive printed the enabled modules, it doesnt show mbstring there, and I have placed a checkup for mb string, that prints MBSTRING NOT RUNNING

Comment: http://www.i2kclasses.com/i2kex_images/editor/status.php

Comment: Usually there are different configuration files (and/or configuration folders) for each SAPI. It looks like mbstring is enabled in the `php-cli` SAPI but not for the webserver (expected apache2, if not, please tell how you actually integrated PHP) . You'll need to make sure that the extension will be enabled by `extension=mbstring.so`, also in your webserver SAPI configs. Then restart the web server

Answer (score 0):

At the terminal, let's first see if you have this on your server:

```
rpm -qa | grep php
```

This command `rpm -qa` list everything installed on your box. Pipe it through `grep` to only show lines containing 'php' and you should see a decent list. On my dev box, I see output as such...

```
$ rpm -qa | grep php
php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-ldap-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-pear-XML-Parser-1.3.4-1.el6.noarch
php-gd-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-pear-1.9.4-4.el6.noarch
php-pear-XML-RSS-1.0.1-1.el6.noarch
php-xml-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-pdo-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
```

Now if you don't see it, attempt to install it via `yum`. If however, your server returns something like **No package php-mbstring available** or like this below:

```
$ sudo yum install php-mbstring
[sudo] password for mr-super-cool: 
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
No package php-mbstring available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

That means you probably need to **subscribe to the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) Repository**. Cyberciti [describes](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-enable-epel-repo/) this as:

> EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) is a volunteer-based
>   community effort from the Fedora project to create a repository of
>   high-quality add-on packages that complement the Fedora-based Red Hat
>   Enterprise Linux (RHEL) and its compatible spinoffs, such as CentOS
>   and Scientific Linux.

That [same page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-enable-epel-repo/) has instructions for RHEL 5 and RHEL 6:

> RHEL 5.x / CentOS 5.x Users
>
> Type the following command as root user to install repo:
>
> ```
> # rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
> ```
>
> RHEL 6.x / CentOS 6.x Users
>
> Type the following command as root user to install repo:
>
> ```
> # rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
> ```

**For RHEL 7**
For RHEL 7 let yum take care of that for you.

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
$ sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Comment: Or the tl;dr version: Install via yum. If that doesn't work, open up the EPEL repo and try again. Restart Apache.